# How to plot polar with data in matlab like this picture

Tags: matlab, plot, polar-coordinates

I have data representing frequency and decibels, and I want to make a polar like this picture:

[image]

What is the command for this?

Answer (score 1):

On [MathWorks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polar.html):

> The polar function accepts polar coordinates, plots them in a Cartesian plane, and draws the polar grid on the plane.
>
> `polar(theta,rho)` creates a polar coordinate plot of the angle `theta` versus the radius `rho`. `theta` is the angle from the x-axis to the radius vector specified in radians; `rho` is the length of the radius vector specified in dataspace units.

You should be able to get your result with `polar(decibels, frequency)`.

Comment: Answers which are basically links are discouraged, especially links which resemble LMGTFY. Please provide a minimum working example, preferably with the resulting plot.